# Adding numeric value from textbox into another textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking for this script everywhere however i was unable to find it. I am trying to create a simple donation count. When a value is added inside a textbox I want it to be permanently fixed into second textbox after button submission. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: post the html of your textboxes

Comment: What precisely do you mean by 'permanently'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var textfield6 = document.getElementById('textfield6');
    textfield6.value = 0;
    document.querySelector('input[type=button]').onclick = function () {
        textfield6.value = parseInt(textfield6.value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('textfield5').value);
    }
}
</script>
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LpKKP/1/)**

Comment: @Marek, updated my answer. Use that code anywhere in your page, inside body or head.

Answer (score 1):

1) First get the value from textBox1 (assuming id=`textbox1`)
2) Assign the value to second textbox (assuming id=`textbox2`)
3) Add the below code in form submission or button click.

```
document.getElementById('textbox2').value =
              document.getElementById('textbox1').value
```

Comment: Maybe `+=` might also be useful here if it's a "donation count"

Comment: @Sergio not sure what OP wants.  But yes has to be used for count increment.

Comment: <input type="text" name="textfield5" id="textfield5" /> //this is the box where the value is put  <input type="text" name="textfield6" id="textfield6" /> // Here the value is added, 0 is the start, when 1 is entered inside "textfield5" i need it to be added with value inside "textfield6". The trigger to adding should be <input type="button" onclick="THE ADDING ACTION" value="Donate" style="height: 35px; width: 120px; font-weight: bold;" />

Comment: @Marek not sure may this fiddle is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/PPEjD/